# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al leer un código de barras con un scanner convencional , esté lo pase pase el código en mi campo código?

Tags: laravel-7, código-de-barras

**Parte del form**

```
<label class="control-label" for="codigo">{{ 'Código:' }}</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" placeholder="Ingresar Código del Material" value="{{ isset($materiales->codigo)?$materiales->codigo:'' }}">
<label class="control-label" for="barcode">{{ 'Código de Barras' }}</label>
{!! isset($materiales->codigo)?DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($materiales->codigo, 'C128'):'
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" action="{{ url("/Materiales") }}"
onclick="printCode()");">Imprimir Etiqueta</button>'; !!}
```

Tengo varías preguntas. Esté es mi formulario en el estoy haciendo que al tener un código ya ingresado manualmente previamente guardado le genere el código y lo muestre en el mismo formulario esa parte me funciona. Resaltando que el form es compartido (Si entra en modo edición llama la ruta correspondiente si entra a la parte de agregar registro llama la ruta de agregar)

solo me gustaría que al escanear el código con el lector me llenara el campo "código". ¿Cómo hago eso cual es la función? **Uso Laravel 7** y el paquete **milon barcode**

[image: Esté es mi form]

Comment: Un lector de código de barras es un dispositivo de entrada, como un teclado; dado que el acceso al hardware desde el navegador es muy restringido por razones de seguridad, actualmente no puedes distinguir a detalle entre dispositivos de entrada sin un tercer componente (plugin, servicio, API experimental, o similar) que opere entre el dispositivo y el navegador.

Comment: Tus alternativas se reducen a la capacidad del lector para configurar secuencias de inicio o fin que puedas detectar en eventos de entrada; o en su defecto tragar eventos de teclado hasta estar seguro que es -o no- un código de barras y proceder en consecuencia.